# Plotting multiple points on google maps, coordinates fetched from database

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I'm working on a laravel project where one enters school coordinates and they are plotted on google maps. I can fetch the coordinates via the controller but plotting it on the map is the issue.

Here is my controller code for fetching the coordinates:

```
public function map_points(){
    $points = DB::table('school_entries')
                    ->select('longitude', 'latitude')
                    ->get();
    $point = array();
    foreach ($points as $value) {
        $point[] = "{latlong: \"$value->latitude,$value->longitude\"}";
    }
    return json_encode($point);
}
```

Here is my json results of the points to be plotted:

```
["{latlong: "30.5350077,-2.161562"}", "{latlong: "30.5480003,-2.0803146"}", "{latlong: "30.0738499,-2.1401087"}", "{latlong: "29.7041765,-2.6116944"}"]
```

Here is my javascript/ajax block of code to plot the points.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/map-points',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function( data ){
                console.log(data);
                var property_list = [data],
                options = {
                    zoom: 8,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng( -2.08, 30.54 ),
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    },
                    map = new google.maps.Map( 
                        document.getElementById( 'map-canvas' ), 
                        options 
                    );
                    for( var index = 0; index < property_list.length; index++ ) {
                        var latlong = property_list[index]['latlong'].split(','),
                            latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( latlong[0], latlong[1] ),
                            marker = new google.maps.Marker( {position: latlng, map: map} );
                        marker.setMap( map );
                    };
                },
                error: function(){
                    output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
                }
            }); 
        });
```

What might be wrong with my code it is not plotting the points?

Comment: Please use url: 'map-points',

Answer (score 0):

The php code to generate the co-ordinates data seems a little complicated - I'm sure you could simplify it like this

```
$point = array();
foreach ($points as $value) {
    $point[] = [
        'lat'=>$value->latitude,
        'lng'=>$value->longitude
    ];
}
return json_encode( $point );
```

and also then modify the javascript callback

```
for( var n in property_list ){
    obj = property_list[n];
    latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( obj.lat, obj.lng );
    marker = new google.maps.Marker( { position: latlng, map: map } );
}
```

So: I took your basic code and the modification I suggested to test to see why you were getting the error. I put together the following demo which correctly plots markers on the map. You will need to excuse the fact that it is based upon a different database with no Laravel code - the important bit is the javascript that process the response data. I hope it helps solve your issue.

```
<?php

    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET' && !empty( $_GET['action'] ) && $_GET['action']='fetch-coordinates' ){
        ob_clean();

        /* emulate the remote script */
        $dbport =   3306;
        $dbhost =   'localhost';
        $dbuser =   'root';
        $dbpwd  =   'xxx';
        $dbname =   'xxx';

        $db = new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );      
        $sql= 'select `lat`,`lng` from `maps`';

        $res=$db->query( $sql );

        $data=[];
        while( $row=$res->fetch_object() ){
            $data[]=[
                'lat'=>$row->lat,
                'lng'=>$row->lng
            ];
        }

        http_response_code( 200 );
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        exit( json_encode( $data ) );
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <script src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js'></script>
        <title>jQuery: Fetch data from db for Google Maps</title>
        <style>
            #map-canvas{width:80%;height:80vh;float:none;margin:auto;border:1px solid black;}
        </style>
        <script>
            $( document ).ready(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/map-points',
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data:{ action:'fetch-coordinates' },
                    success: function( data ){
                        var options = {
                            zoom: 8,
                            center: new google.maps.LatLng( -2.08, 30.54 ),
                            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                        };
                        var map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById( 'map-canvas' ), options );

                        for( var n in data ){
                            var obj = data[ n ];
                            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( obj.lat, obj.lng );
                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker( { position: latlng, map: map } );
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(e){
                        output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
                    }
                }); 
            });
        </script>
        <script src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxoFYApo9VMdJzE04tAxxxx'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='map-canvas'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @RamRider before the forloop in the javascript call back is there something else I should change because this change hasn't plotted yet.

Comment: check the console for errors and perhaps add a debug `console.info(obj.lat,obj.lng)` in the loop

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
That's the error I am getting.

Comment: looking at `var property_list = [data]` it seems you are casting the json into an array? Simply `var property_list = data` perhaps

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by simply having to fetch data from the controller as is(since laravel return json objects) like the below function :

```
public function map_points(){
    $points = SchoolEntry::select('longitude', 'latitude')->get();
    return json_encode($points);
}
```

and in my javascript had to do the following to plot the point

```
var property_list = data,
options = {
   zoom: 8,center: new google.maps.LatLng( -2.08, 30.54 ),mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP },
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById( 'map-canvas' ),options);

   for( var index = 0; index < property_list.length; index++ ) {
        console.log(property_list[index]);
        var latlong = property_list[index],
        latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( latlong.longitude, latlong.latitude ),
        marker = new google.maps.Marker( {position: latlng, map: map} );
        marker.setMap( map );
   };
```

The above plotted the points perfectly.